# Having trouble adding a friend

Tags: steam

I don't know why, but I can't seem to add someone as a friend.

Whenever I click add as friend, it says "Friend invite sent".

What doesn't show up is an "invitations sent" listing on my friends list.

This is pretty frustrating any help? I've been using both the browser version and steam client to try to add as a friend.

Comment: Is your client set to display offline friends?  Friend invites should appear after that, unless something else is wrong.

Comment: yeah, offline and online friends appear fine.

Comment: Friends who haven't accepted should be shown at the very bottom of the friends list (below offline) - are you sure they're not there?

Comment: Definitely.  I can hit add friend, have the bottom of the friends list open, and nothing will register as "invitation sent"

Comment: Neither of you are over the limit of number of friends?

Comment: no i have 200 empty friends list slots

Comment: This happens to me as well. I'm pretty sure it's a bug with Steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to block the person you are trying to add then unblock them and then add them again.

Also, have you been able to add other people?

*Their friendslist may also be full!*

Comment: Do you mean "unblock" instead of "re-block"?

Comment: Haha, yes. Oops.. Have to change that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding the Friends by account name? If so i also have had trouble and usually the email address works better.

If that doesn't work then add them by friend ID.